# Touch or click Event for detecting top/bottom/left/right of screen in android

Tags: android

**What i have tried**:

By implementing SwipeInterface in my activity i can detect the swipe event

---

**SwipeInterface.java**

```
import android.view.View;

public interface SwipeInterface {

    public void bottom2top(View v);

    public void left2right(View v);

    public void right2left(View v);

    public void top2bottom(View v);

}
```

**ActivitySwipeDetector.java**

```
public class ActivitySwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

    static final String logTag = "ActivitySwipeDetector";
    private SwipeInterface activity;
    static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;

    public ActivitySwipeDetector(SwipeInterface activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void onRightToLeftSwipe(View v){
        Log.i(logTag, "RightToLeftSwipe!");
        activity.right2left(v);
    }

    public void onLeftToRightSwipe(View v){
        Log.i(logTag, "LeftToRightSwipe!");
        activity.left2right(v);
    }

    public void onTopToBottomSwipe(View v){
        Log.i(logTag, "onTopToBottomSwipe!");
        activity.top2bottom(v);
    }

    public void onBottomToTopSwipe(View v){
        Log.i(logTag, "onBottomToTopSwipe!");
        activity.bottom2top(v);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downX = event.getX();
            downY = event.getY();
            return true;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            upX = event.getX();
            upY = event.getY();

            float deltaX = downX - upX;
            float deltaY = downY - upY;

            // swipe horizontal?
            if(Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE){
                // left or right
                if(deltaX < 0) { this.onLeftToRightSwipe(v); return true; }
                if(deltaX > 0) { this.onRightToLeftSwipe(v); return true; }
            }
            else {
                Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
            }

            // swipe vertical?
            if(Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE){
                // top or down
                if(deltaY < 0) { this.onTopToBottomSwipe(v); return true; }
                if(deltaY > 0) { this.onBottomToTopSwipe(v); return true; }
            }
            else {
                Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                v.performClick();
            }
        }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

---

### What i am having a problem

- So if i have a widget say a gridview to a full screen i am not able
  to detect the swipe event because gridview is taking the event

**What i am trying to do:**

- So as a workaround idea what i have is, to detect the event when the
  screen is touched on the corner of the screen(top/bottom/left/right)
- Is there any event like that
- What is that event name
- Any sample i can use

Comment: Try adding `android:focusable="false"` to your your `GridView` xml